# Powershell time delay between each ping which is unreachable or timed out

Tags: powershell

I am writing a program that will do a ping test on multiple devices and record the ping status into a CSV log file. From this picture
[csv example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV5CQ.png), on the log time (time receives the ping response), there are about 2-4 seconds between each of them.

The question is how can I reduce it to only 1 second between each of them? Below is the code that do the ping:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 4; $i++) {
    $ping = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address = '$ipAddress'" 
    $time = Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss"
}
```

Comment: `-Filter "Address = '$ipAddress and timeout = 1000'"`. Timeout is in milliseconds, so 1000 --> 1 second

Comment: Or check out [Test-Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-5.1#parameters) or [Test-NetConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=windowsserver2019-ps)